# How do I use both stop loss and take profit in pinescript v5 ? (Three methods)

Tags: pine-script-v5

I'd like to get the stop loss and take profit to trigger and print on the chart. The stop loss and take profit should both be set to 1% from the entry for both long and short positions.

**Method 1: Initiate the take profit order immediately after entry**

```
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("BB Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG WIN", from_entry="BB Long", limit=high * 1.01)
```

Can I initiate both the stop loss and take profit orders in the same way, immediately after the entry? Example:

```
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("BB Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG WIN", from_entry="BB Long", limit=high * 1.01)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG STOP", from_entry="BB Long", stop=open * 0.99)
```

So far I'm not able to get it working with method 1 for both stop loss and take profit.

**Method 2: I've seen this example in a few scripts. If I can't use both takeprofit and stop loss in method 1, when would I need to use this instead?**

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG STOP", from_entry="BB Long", stop=open * 0.99)
```

Using method 1 for the take profit and method 2 for the stop loss, I'm getting varying success. The script still isn't printing the closing of the positions on the chart for both take profit and stop loss.

**Method 3: Instead of using strategy.exit() , use strategy.close() . Can someone explain the differences to me?**

Can you help me understand what I should be doing to achieve my goal for this script?

For the sake of completeness, here is the script as I have it currently.

```
//@version=5
strategy(shorttitle="BB Multi", title="Bollinger Bands Strategy", overlay=true)

// Set input parameters
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
mult = input.float(2.5, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)

// Calculate Bollinger Bands using 15 minute data
src = close
middle = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = middle + dev
lower = middle - dev

// Calculate Bollinger Bands using 1 hour data
src1h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '60', close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
middle1h = ta.sma(src1h, length)
dev1h = mult * ta.stdev(src1h, length)
upper1h = middle1h + dev1h
lower1h = middle1h - dev1h

// Enter long position when 15 minute chart Bollinger Band is touched and the 1 hour band is touched
longCondition = ta.crossover(low, lower) and (ta.crossover(low, lower1h) or ta.crossover(low[1], lower1h))
if longCondition
    strategy.entry("BB Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG WIN", from_entry="BB Long", limit=high * 1.01)
    
// Enter short position when 15 minute chart Bollinger Band is touched and the 1 hour band is touched
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(high, upper) and (ta.crossover(high, upper1h) or ta.crossover(high[1], upper1h))
if shortCondition
    strategy.entry("BB Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("EXIT SHORT WIN", from_entry="BB Short", limit=low * 0.09)

// Plot Bollinger Bands
plot(upper, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(lower, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plot(upper1h, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot(lower1h, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("EXIT LONG STOP", from_entry="BB Long", stop=open * 0.99)
   
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("EXIT SHORT STOP", from_entry="BB Short", stop=open * 1.01)
```

I have written a few scripts from cobbled together pieces of code but I'm now trying to get a better understanding of the functions. I've tried combinations of different methods but I'm still not getting both the take profit and the stop loss to trigger as well as display on the chart.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, so the first solution I found is this:**

```
strategy.exit("TP / SL", from_entry="BB Long", limit=high * 1.01, stop=initialEntryPrice * 0.99)
```

The take profit and stop loss are placed in the same strategy.exit() function. However, this doesn't plot in on the graph in the way that I want. I would want to see just TP or SL, depending on the case. In this solution, it will plot "TP / SL" whenever it exits a trade, for either reason. This is ok, but if anyone has can answer my other questions I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

**This one plots on the graph:**

```
strategy.exit("TP / SL", "BB Long", limit=strategy.position_avg_price * 1.01, stop=strategy.position_avg_price * 0.99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "loss", "profit" and "comment_loss" and "comment_profit"

```
strategy.exit("BB Long", loss = 300, profit = 600, comment_loss = "Loss", comment_profit = "Win")
```